# sub setting panel data based on two variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
id <- c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3),rep(3,4))
missing <- c(rep(0,4),rep(0,3),1,0,0,0)
wave <- c(seq(1:4),1,2,3,seq(1:4))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,missing,wave)) 
df



id missing wave
1   1       0    1
2   1       0    2
3   1       0    3
4   1       0    4
5   2       0    1
6   2       0    2
7   2       0    3
8   3       1    1
9   3       0    2
10  3       0    3
11  3       0    4
```

I am trying to delete cases if they have missing=1 or if they are missing a wave (1:4). For example, ID=3 should be dropped because at wave=1 they have missing=1 and ID=2 should be dropped because they only have values of 1, 2, and 3 in Wave.

I tried to use dplyr's group_by and filter functions but this removes all cases. I want to only end up with cases for ID=1.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(missing==0, wave==1, wave==2, wave==3, wave==4)
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. We first `group_by` `id`, and then create a list column with the sorted unique values of `wave` for each `id`. Then we check to make sure this list equals `1:4`. We create a `missing_check` variable, which is just the `max` of `missing` for each `id`. We filter on both `missing_check` and `wave_check`.

```
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(wave_list = I(list(sort(unique(wave))))) %>%
    mutate(wave_list_check = all(unlist(wave_list) == 1:4),
           missing_check = max(missing)) %>%
    filter(missing_check == 0, wave_list_check) %>%
    select(id:wave)

     id missing  wave
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1     1       0     1
2     1       0     2
3     1       0     3
4     1       0     4
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited the data frame to reflect both conditions I wish to drop. I ran your suggested solution but I received a warning:

Warning message:
In unlist(wave_list) == 1:4 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

and it didn't drop ID=2 or 3

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your updated data. This warning comes from checking if `unlist(wave_list) == 1:4 `, you get the same warning and desired result by checking `1:3 == 1:4`

Comment: You're welcome! You had a great reproducible example for your question and a clear explanation of what you were trying to do. Way to go!